# How to update multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called users .

Users {name, team_id, overall_user_score}

I want to select all from a team (eg all from team 2) and add 1 to each users overall score taking into account the current score of each user.

I have the first part of the MySQL done, But I cant figure out how to actually update the score.

```
SELECT * from users WHERE team_id = $team UPDATE overall_user_score
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct SQL Query for updating.

```
UPDATE `users` SET `overall_user_score`=`overall_user_score`+1 WHERE team_id= "'.$team.'"
```

Comment: From what I understand , that would replace the users score with a value. What if they already have something in the overall score value.

Comment: UPDATE `users` SET `overall_user_score`=`overall_user_score`+1 WHERE team_id= "'.$team.'"

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `users` SET `overall_user_score`=overall_user_score + 1 WHERE team_id= "'.$team.'"
```

this should work